# Programacion Generica no me funciona metodo compareTo en objetos de tipo GregorianCALENDAR

Tags: java

Estoy practicando con un ejercicio de un método genérico, con 2 objetos, el primero un `array` de `String` que el método `getElemento` lo imprime por consola correctamente, pero después cuando intento hacer lo mismo con una `array` de tipo `GregorianCalendar` me imprime cualquier cosa.

En el método `getElemento`, estoy comparando objetos mediante la interfaz Comparable, utilizando el método `compareTo`.

```
import java.util.*;

public class CreacionClaseGenerica7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        //PRIMER ARRAY STRING
        
        String []nombreDePersonas= {"Antonio","Jose", "Gonzalo", "Dario"};//
        
        System.out.println(ArraysGenericos.getElemento(nombreDePersonas));//LO LEE PERFECTO
        
        //SEGUNDO ARRAY GREGORIANCALENDAR
        
        GregorianCalendar [] fechas=new GregorianCalendar[5];
        
        fechas[0]=new GregorianCalendar(2019,3,7);
        
        fechas[1]=new GregorianCalendar(2018,3,7);

        fechas[2]=new GregorianCalendar(2017,3,7);

        fechas[3]=new GregorianCalendar(2016,3,7);

        fechas[4]=new GregorianCalendar(2015,3,7);
        
        System.out.println(ArraysGenericos.getElemento(fechas));//LO LEE MAL
    }

}
```

---

```
class ArraysGenericos{
    
    public static <T extends Comparable>T getElemento(T[]elArray){//METODO GENERICO
        
    T objetoMenor=elArray[0];
    
    for(int i=1;i<elArray.length;i++) {
        
        if(objetoMenor.compareTo(elArray[i])>0) {
            
            objetoMenor=elArray[i];
            
        }
        
    }
    
    return objetoMenor;
        
    }
        
        
}
```

---

Salida por pantalla:

> Antonio//METODO STRING PERFECTO
>
> java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Buenos_Aires",offset=-10800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=62,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=?,YEAR=2015,MONTH=3,WEEK_OF_YEAR=?,WEEK_OF_MONTH=?,DAY_OF_MONTH=7,DAY_OF_YEAR=?,DAY_OF_WEEK=?,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=?,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=?,ZONE_OFFSET=?,DST_OFFSET=?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No imprime cualquier cosa, es que es de Tipo`GregorianCalendar`, solo tenes que pasarlo a `Date` con el método `getTime()`. Entonces ahi en el main cuando pedís la fecha por consola le agregas `.getTime()`, así:

```
System.out.println(ArraysGenericos.getElemento(fechas).getTime());
```

Después si lo querés en otro formato, por ejemplo este:
2019-07-28

```
DateFormat dfFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String sFecha=dfFecha.format(ArraysGenericos.getElemento(fechas).getTime());
```

Tené en cuenta que la fecha formateada está en `String`, ahora la mostras:

```
System.out.println(sFecha);
```

Comment: Excelente explicacion. Gracias